# How to define precision@k in this KDD paper?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, recommender-system, precision-recall, precision

I am following this KDD paper trying to learn new things: http://keg.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn/jietang/publications/KDD12-Tang-et-al-Cross-Domain-Collaboration-Recommendation.pdf

In the results section they present the values of `precision@10 (p@10)` (see Table 2 of the paper). 
[image]

In my understanding `p@10` reflects how many correct recommendations are in top 10 recommendations. So if we get `6` correct out of `10`, the `p@10 = 0.6`. So in other words, the `p@10` can be either of the following values `{0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0}`.

However, in the table 2 of this paper, they have some unusual values for p@10 such as `10.3%`. So, this is equal to `0.103`. My question is these values do not fall in the possible values p@10 can take: `{0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0}`.

Please let me know your thoughts in how this paper has calculated p@10.

I am happy to provide more examples if needed.

Answer (score 1):

p@10 is indeed precision at 10, but normally you would perform something like cross validation and take the averages across the many train-test repetitions.

So my guess is that the values you see on the table are the averages across test datasets. You are right it's not very clear in the methods.

I checked the paper, there is a section under "Evaluation metrics":

> To quantitatively evaluate the proposed methods, in each test case, we
>   use historic collaboration data (data before 2001) for training and
>   the last four years (2001-2005) for validation

So most like the values you see are averages across years or whatever test case might entail.. just my educated guess

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I checked if the paper contains the word "cross validation". It doesn't explicitly say so. please kindly let me know if you got any further suggestions. thank you. I will try to contact author too :)

Comment: Hi @EmJ, I am not so familiar with this field, i think it might be they test each year separately (more or less you can treat them as separate datasets) but then again... doesn't look like numbers divided by 5.. so it's not clear